# LIfetime of a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, lifetime

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the lifetime of global variable x below. I have commented my question on the line that I am not understanding.. please help... thanksss

```
var target = document.getElementById("outputArea");
var outString = "";

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

callMeOften2();
callMeOften2();
callMeOften2();
outString += "<br/>";

target.innerHTML = outString;

function callMeOften2() {
    outString += x + "<br/>"; //why isn't this going to give an output of 0? but gave an output of undefined instead? isn't x referring to the global variable x?
    var x = 100;

    x = x + 100;
    outString += "from callMeoften2: " + "x = " + x + "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how all Javascript Engines through variable hoisting plays with your code (effectively)

```
function callMeOften2() {
    var x = undefined;
    outString += x + "<br/>"; //why isn't this going to give an output of 0? but gave an output of undefined instead? isn't x referring to the global variable x?
    x = 100;

    x = x + 100;
    outString += "from callMeoften2: " + "x = " + x + "<br/>";
}
```

Hope this helps

The `var x` in the function means the global `x` is irrelevant (of course can be accessed using `window.x` in a browser, ro some other "global" object in other environments)

Comment: How does the JVM enter into this?

Comment: sorry, bad term - not sure why I recently started referering to Javascript Engines as JVM's!! I keep doing it too! I hate Java almost as much as I hate JQueery!!

Comment: To be fair though, JVM can be an abbreviation of Javascript Virtual Machine, which is a thing, so, Java programmers will just have to suffer in silence

Comment: so whenever a variable which has the same name as global variable is declared in a function... no matter what location.. when the variable is mentioned even before the local variable is declared... then.. this variable is still referring to the not yet declared local variable?

Comment: a variable declaration is hoisted to the top of the current scope. what exists in other scopes is irrelevant

Comment: ohhh i see! thanks.. makes a lot more sense :D